# In TOAD: Is it possible to add custom validation on user/schema field in Toad for Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle11g, toad

Recently we are seeing security violation as users were sharing credential with other. We would liked to enforce validation on user field so that we can detect the violation before it reaches database

I could see options are available to execute app/action upon connect, but this wont help us as users would've connected to DB using others credentials already. Need to stop the connection if validation fails

Comment: Sounds like you want a [LOGON DDL trigger](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/triggers.htm#CIHEFABC) to check the [OS user id](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:31051406979835). Of course, that won't help if your users are sharing their OS accounts (e.g. a service account)!

Comment: yeah i need some validation before toad attempt to connect to DB. In the validation, i would like to perform validation to make sure username entered is not of OS userid pattern if its not user's OS userid. hope this helps. Also this has to happen in Toad not in DB end.

Comment: Toad does not have any mechanism for providing your own validation. Set your Oracle users up for OS authentication and you should be set.

Comment: i can understand, but sometime users need to connect to DB using service accounts, so restricting to OS authentication wont solve the complete problme

Comment: You'd only set up the external authentication for those user logins that require it. [This article](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/os-authentication) might help you. You can have a mix of externally identified and local password schemas on a database.